# Google Apps Script redirect uri error

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make a standalone Google Apps Script to access an API through the OAuth2 library, found here: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

I have not been able to get any of the examples to work so far, but I think it's because I cannot register my application and set the OAuth redirect URI.  This is my first attempt at using OAuth.

Here are the steps I've taken:

1. Create a new standalone Google App Script
2. Paste in the contents of Dropbox.gs (for this example)
3. Add the OAuth2 library to my script
   (Resources > Libraries, and paste in the ID listed in the how-to)
4. Go to the console (Resources > Cloud Platform project) and navigate to
   the APIs & Services > Credentials page
5. Grab the Client ID and Client secret from that page and paste them into my script.
6. Get the redirect URI from the script (by running logRedirectUri())
7. Paste the redirect URI into the cloud platform console, and hit save.

I get the error shown at this link (which reads "You do not have permission to perform this action.

[Request URI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L2zX.png)

From what I've studied, I need this URI entered in order to make this script work.  Why won't this save?

Comment: I should also point out that if I try to run these samples without the redirect URI entered, I get "Invalid Client ID" issues when I attempt to run the authorization URL.

Comment: Are you on a google app domain?

Comment: If you are signed into multiple google accounts in the browser, the console may not "know" what account it being used.  Log out of all accounts, and log into only the one you want to use for this web app.

Comment: Also, see the following post at Web Applications [Register your Apps Script application and retrieve the client ID and secret for oAuth dance](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88167/69407)

Comment: Jason, just a normal gmail account.  Sandy, I'm only signed in as the one user, but I tried incognito for good measure. The instructions you gave are essentially what I tried.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some things you can try.

**Step one**

**The web app api**

Change from using the appscript API to using a web app API. You can create a new one in the API admin console.

[image]

Then select the web app option.

[image]

Finally you will have a new API.

[image]

Open the new API and get the client ID and secrets.

Paste into the api the redirect from your app.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback
```

**Step two**

**The authentication and redirect**

The next bit is tricky and may need some fiddling.

The first part of the code below generates a URL. The user then needs to be directed to open the generated URL in a new window. The new window will show all the usual google permissions including any scopes. When the user accepts they will be redirected back to your app.

```
function getAuthURL() {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  if (!driveService.hasAccess()) {
    var authorizationUrl = driveService.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log(authorizationUrl)
}

function authCallback(request) {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  var isAuthorized = driveService.handleCallback(request);
  if (isAuthorized) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
  }
}
```

**Step three**

**The access token**

Now the user gave permission it is possible to get the access token and pass it along on with fetch requests.

```
function makeRequest() {
  var driveService = getDriveService();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=10', {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + driveService.getAccessToken()
    }
  });
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi, Jason - thanks!  I don't know if a bug was fixed, or your trick worked, but creating new credentials did in fact allow me to enter the redirect URI. So that's progress!  I'm still not having luck when I navigate to the authorization URL: "It seems the app you were using submitted a bad request. If you would like to report this error to the app's developer, include the information below."  I'll keep trying.

Comment: I spent a few more hours working on this.  I've gone back and forth with the client ID (and secret) from the app script API (which doesn't have the redirect URI), and those from the new web app API (which does have the redirect URI).  When I visit the authorization URL from either setup, the same thing happens.  The only difference is the client ID in the error message.

Comment: Hi There is something else at play also. Google doesn't like the use of this library by just anyone. From my side I found that they revoke any token I make within about 10 minutes. This only happens on my private account. When I run the same code on our domain it runs okay.